# Excel: choosing lowest status in a list

Tags: excel, function

I have a tab "Ranges" with values in A1 to A4:

```
In Progress
Planned
Ready
Done
```

I have a tab "Features", with columns ID, Name, Status. Status can have one of the values from Ranges:

```
ID    Name    Status
1     AAA     Planned
1     AAA     In Progress
2     BBB     Done
2     BBB     Ready
2     BBB     Planned
```

I want to be able to get the LOWEST status (from Ranges list)of a certain feature.
For example for feature AAA (id 1) I will get "In Progress" (the lowest one).
For BBB it is "Planned".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this array formula, where the name of the current project is in G2:-

```
=INDEX(Ranges!$A$1:$A$4,MIN(IF($B$2:$B$6=G2,MATCH($C$2:$C$6,Ranges!$A$1:$A$4,0))))
```

Must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

You could also just add a helper column containing

```
=MATCH(C2,Ranges!$A$1:$A$4,0)
```

And use a pivot table, with Name as your row variable and min of the new column in your values field.

Comment: Tom do you know how it can be translated to Google Sheets? ARRAYFORMULA did not provide the solution...

Comment: That's strange, it worked for me when I tried it just now with =
ArrayFormula(INDEX(Ranges!$A$1:$A$4,MIN(IF($B$2:$B$6=G2,MATCH($C$2:$C$6,Ranges!$A$1:$A$4,0)))))

Answer (score 0):

If you set the data in the 'Features' tab within a table, after you finish manipulating the data you could then set the filters on the 'Status' column to only show the range that you are looking for.  Otherwise you would have to have a third tab or area where you could setup a pivot table that could be used as a report to only show the desired status.  The third way I have done this is with a series of array formulas to generate a report in a similar fashion to how the pivot tables would have.

So do you want to sort your active data or do you want a third tab or area to generate a report based on the data on the 'Features' tab?